# When can we say $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{n} f_n(x) \,dx =\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let's consider $ (f_n)_n$ a sequence of mesurable functions. Let's say the sequence has the measurable function f as limit.
Let's consider $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's also consider for convenience $f_n$ is integrable in a neighborhood of $a$ for all $n$ and f is integrable in a neighborhood of $a$.

**I would like to know under which hypothesis we could say** $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{n} f_n(x) \,dx =\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx $

**Why i'm asking this question here :** Most of theorems i know , involving either uniform convergence or monotone convergence theorem , dominate convergence theorem , doesn't really apply in my opinion because of the dependence in the integration set.

I think maybe the fact that the right and left terms are definite (in the finite sense) could be enough but i think i may be wrong.

Comment: If you are familiar with Lebesgue integration, integrability of $f$ over $(a,\infty)$ or positivity of $f$ ($f\geq0$) on some interval $(b,\infty)$, $a<b$, will suffice as then you can apply dominated convergence (in case of integrability) or monotone convergence theorem (positivity of $f$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the dependence in the domain of integration by writing
$$\int_a^n f_n(x) \, dx = \int_a^\infty f_n(x) \chi_{[a,n]}(x) \, dx.$$ At this point it is a matter of using the correct convergence result.

For instance, if $f_n(x) \nearrow f(x)$ on $[a,\infty)$ then $f_n(x) \chi_{[a,n]}(x) \nearrow f(x)$ there too because $\chi_{[a,n]} \nearrow 1$ on $[a,\infty)$. You could apply MCT.

On the other hand, if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ almost everywhere on $[a,\infty)$ and there is a function $g \in L^1([a,\infty))$ with $|f_n(x)| \le g(x)$, then $f_n(x) \chi_{[a,n]}(x) \to f(x)$ almost everywhere (again because $\chi_{[a,n]} \to 1$ on $[a,\infty)$) so you could apply LDCT since $|f_n(x) \chi_{[a,n]}(x)| \le |f_n(x)| \le g(x)$.